# How to transform an array into a new array

Tags: javascript

How can I transform values from an array to a new array?

I have an array like:

```
[
  { "amount" : 10, "date" : "2017-05-30" }...
]
```

which I want to "transform" into

```
[
  { x : 10, y: 2017-05-30 }
]
```

any help is appreciated...

Comment: Do you just want to change the names of the object keys?

Comment: @PeterMader basically yes :-)

Comment: I wonder why normal posting rules never apply when people can answer full code in less than 30 seconds... does the easy rep take priority over the quality of the question... even the question now has 2 upvotes (which I assume is to attract attention to the answers)... where are the comments asking for the OP to show what they have tried?? Not to mention the duplicates!

Answer (score 7):

You could map new objects with the new properties.

```js
var array = [{ amount: 10, date: "2017-05-30" }],
    newArray = array.map(a => ({ x: a.amount, y: a.date }));

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `Array#map()`

The callback function will create a new object with the 2 properties needed. You just have to keep the value of the current array

```js
const array = [{ "amount" : 10, "date" : "2017-05-30" }];

let newArray = array.map(_=>({x:_.amount,y:_.date}));
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using lodash map [Lodash map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map)

It will be something like:

```
const array2 = _.map(array1, (item) => { x: item.amount, y: item.date });
```